# Count values of a dictionary matching a REGEX

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I would like to count the values matching a regex in a dictionary...

My regex is this one:

```
regex: (\D)
#The dictionary:
mydict = {"code" : "a208889", "Number" : "23"}
```

I would like to count the "codes" that have non-numeric characters inside...

**I tried:**

- Transforming the dictionary to a string and using len.(findall(r'')) with another regex, but it takes a lot of time while it works (the dictionary has a lot of values).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Changed! there was a typo in my question, the regex is only \D (to search for non-numeric characters)

Answer (score 1):

You can count dictionary keys that contain values with at least one non-numeric char using

```py
len([k for k,v in mydict.items() if any(not c.isdigit() for c in v)])
```

If you want to use your regex, you need to use

```py
pattern = r'\D'
len([k for k,v in mydict.items() if re.search(pattern, v)])
```